# VB.net with looping problem in inserting data

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have datagridview with columns `Ending, PumpNo, NozzleNo, TankID`.
Example of data from datagridview:

> ```
> PumpNo    NozzleNo    TankID       Ending
>
>    1          1       1-BIODIESEL  *This part is where user input ending for every pumpno, nozzle, and tankid*
> ```

This is an example of inserting. On the first insert, `Opening` will be set to 0:

[image]

When you insert for the 2nd time, it should loop in the datagridview and get all details and save them to the database. Afterwards, `select top 1 ending order by desc` from the past record you have in database and that will be your opening to your 2nd insert. See the picture below with yellow highlight:

[image]

**The problem is**

I'm just getting the `Ending` from the last record. As shown below where all Endings are 8.9

[image]

I think i should have filter before inserting like `pumpno = @pumpno and nozzleno = @nozzleno and TankID = @tankid` so that when I insert into table, I will get the designated top 1 ending based on what I filter.

My Code:

```vb
  Dim Ending As Decimal
            'This is my code in selecting top 1 ending 
            SelectQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 Ending FROM DigitalTB WHERE PumpNo = @Pump1 AND NozzleNo = @Nozzle1 AND TankID = @Tank1 ORDER BY Ending DESC"
            cmd = New SqlCommand
            With cmd
                .Connection = Connections.cn
                .CommandText = SelectQuery
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Pump1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10))
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Nozzle1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10))
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Tank1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100))

                Dim pump1 As String = String.Empty
                Dim nozzle As String = String.Empty
                Dim tankid As String = String.Empty
```

I loop here in my datagridview for able to use as my filter when selecting top 1 ending in my select query:

```vb
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvDigital.Rows
                    pump1 = row.Cells(1).Value
                    nozzle = row.Cells(2).Value
                    tankid = row.Cells(3).Value

                    .Parameters("@Pump1").Value = pump1
                    .Parameters("@Nozzle1").Value = nozzle
                    .Parameters("@Tank1").Value = tankid
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Then using sqlreader I will read all that I get from my `select top 1 ending` query. In this part when I `msgbox(ending)` it works perfectly, but when I put the insert here it will select top 1 first in first row then insert and loop doesn't work here.

```vb
                    Using read As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                        If read.Read Then
                            Ending = read("Ending")
                            read.Close()
'Msgbox(Ending)
                        End If
                    End Using
                Next
            End With
```

This is my insert code where I get the details in my table and insert them into my database. I would want to have a filter here:

```vb
            'Inserting code
            InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO DigitalTB(PumpNo,NozzleNo,TankID,Opening,Ending,ReadingType,UserShift,Date,Time)" &
                " VALUES(@PumpNo1,@NozzleNo1,@TankID1,@Opening1,@Ending1,@ReadingType1,@UserShift1,@Date1,@Time1)"
            cmd = New SqlCommand
            With cmd
                .Connection = Connections.cn
                .CommandText = InsertQuery
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Ending", SqlDbType.Decimal))
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@PumpNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10))
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@NozzleNo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10))
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@TankID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100))

                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Opening", Ending)  ' This part is where i insert the top 1 from ending
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserShift", Interfacefrm.lblUserInterface.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReadingType", "Fuel")
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", Date.Now.ToShortDateString) 'I save it as string
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", Date.Now.ToShortTimeString) 'I save it as string
            End With

            For i As Integer = 0 To Me.dgvDigital.Rows.Count - 1
                With cmd
                    .Parameters(0).Value = Me.dgvDigital.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
                    .Parameters(1).Value = Me.dgvDigital.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
                    .Parameters(2).Value = Me.dgvDigital.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
                    .Parameters(3).Value = Me.dgvDigital.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                End With
            Next
            MsgBox("Success Inserting")
```

Answer (score 1):

I already answered my question. By using the subquery *select inside my values to get the output i want.*

```vb
 Connections.connect()
                InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO DigitalTB(PumpNo,NozzleNo,TankID,Opening,Ending,ReadingType,UserShift,Date,Time)" &
                " VALUES(@PumpNo1,@NozzleNo1,@TankID1,(SELECT TOP 1 Ending FROM DigitalTB WHERE PumpNo = @PumpNo1 AND NozzleNo = @NozzleNo1 AND TankID = @TankID1 ORDER BY Ending DESC),@Ending1,@ReadingType1,@UserShift1,@Date1,@Time1)"



            cmd = New SqlCommand
            With cmd
                .Connection = Connections.cn
                .CommandText = InsertQuery
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Ending1", SqlDbType.Decimal))
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@PumpNo1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10))
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@NozzleNo1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10))
                .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@TankID1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100))

                '  .Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Opening1", Ending))   ' This part is where i insert the top 1 from ending
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserShift1", Interfacefrm.lblUserInterface.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReadingType1", "Fuel")
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date1", Date.Now.ToShortDateString) 'I save it as string
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time1", Date.Now.ToShortTimeString) 'I save it as string

                For i As Integer = 0 To Me.dgvDigital.Rows.Count - 1
                    With cmd
                        .Parameters(0).Value = Me.dgvDigital.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
                        .Parameters(1).Value = Me.dgvDigital.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
                        .Parameters(2).Value = Me.dgvDigital.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
                        .Parameters(3).Value = Me.dgvDigital.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
                        .ExecuteNonQuery()
                    End With
                Next

            End With
            MsgBox("Success Inserting")
            Connections.disconnect()
```